# Select2 Autocomplete & Tagging not working Rails 5

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, jquery-select2

I'm building a rails 5 App and integrating a Tagging feature using acts_as_taggable_on, select2, and simple_form gems.

So essentially what I'm trying to do is tag a product on the new product form, if the tag exists in an autocomplete dropdown box then use the existing tag, if not create the tag.

Right now, I'm at a bit of loggerhead and not sure where I'm going wrong.

All that I get on the form is an empty multi-select box (below)
[image]

this should appear as a text field with a dropdown that fills as the user enters in the tag names.

**Product Controller "new" and "create" actions and the product_params method:**

```
  def new
    @product = Product.new

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.json { render json: @product }
    end
  end

  def create
    @product = Product.new(product_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @product.valid?

        @product.save
        format.html { redirect_to @product, flash: { success: "#{@product.name.titleize} has been created & added to the store." } }
        format.json { render json: @product, status: :created, location: @project }
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
        format.json { render json: @product.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

    def product_params
      params.require(:product).permit(:name, :description, :price, :tag_list, tag_list: [])
    end
```

**My Js:**

```
// JS Initializer
$(document).on('turbolinks:load', function() {
  // Select2 Tag Creation
  $('.multiple-input').each(function() {
    $(this).select2({
      tags: true,
      tokenSeperators: [','],
      theme: 'bootstrap',
      placeholder: 'seperated by space'
    });
  });
  // Select2 Autocomplete
  $('#product-autocomplete').select2({
      ajax: {
        url: "/products.json",
        dataType: json,
        results: function(data, page) {
          return {
            results: $.map( data, function(product.tag_list, i) {
              return { id: product.id, text: product.tag.name }
            } )
          }
        }
      }
  });

});
```

**My simple_form input:**

```
  <%= f.input :tag_list, input_html: { class: 'multiple-input', id: 'product-autocomplete', multiple: "multiple"}, collection: @product.tag_list %>
```

I've tried a few other ways of implementing this with no luck, I think this is going to really boil down to the JS, and that is my Achilles heel. I'm learning but really struggling with this. Any assistance here would be greatly appreciated! Please if I have missed any pertinent info let me know I'll be happy to post!

**EDIT 1:** 
Im adding a pic of the error my google inspect console is spitting out.

Note: the url: reads /products.json not the @product shown in the image.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I needed to do a few things to hook this all up..

**1. Add Tags Controller and a resource route to call the tags_list**

```
class TagsController < ApplicationController

  def index
    tags = ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag
      .where("name ILIKE ?", "%#{params[:term]}%")
      .select("id, name as text")

    respond_to do |format|
      format.json {render json: tags}
    end
  end

end

resources :tags, only: [:index]
```

**2) Fix JS to populate the autocomplete dropdown:**

```
// JS Initializer
$(document).on('turbolinks:load', function() {
  // Select2 Tag Creation
  $('.multiple-input').each(function() {
    $(this).select2({
      tags: true,
      tokenSeperators: [','],
      theme: 'bootstrap',
      placeholder: 'seperated by space',
      minimumInputLength: 3,
      ajax: {
        url: "/tags.json",
        dataType: 'json',
        processResults: function(data) {
          console.log(data)
          return {results: data};
        }
      }
    });
  });

});
```